# How to Update the FS Manufacturer and Model on Stock Items using Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to update the Manufacturer and Manufacturer Model on the "Service Management" tab of the Stock Item (IN202500).

I'm about 99% sure that they must be in a Graph Extension, but the Schema Browser only indicates that they are in a DLL, not the name of the extension. More generically, if a field is in an Extension, is there a way to find out which one? Or enumerate the extensions that exist in a Graph Cache?

```cs
InventoryItem row = Base.ItemSettings.Current;

// This doesn't work. InventoryItemFSxEquipmentModel isn't the name of the extension and IDK how I figure out what it is.
InventoryItemFSxEquipmentModel rowExt2 = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<InventoryItemFSxEquipmentModel>(row);

// This also doesn't work, as it isn't in the base model.
throw new PXException(row.ManufacturerID.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out which graph extension a field is in, you can use the "Customization Project Editor" in Acumatica:

1. Open the "Customization Project Editor" (SM204505) screen in Acumatica.
2. In the "Object Name" field, type "`InventoryItem`" and click "Search".
3. Click the "+" icon next to "InventoryItem" to expand the list of customization items for the InventoryItem DAC.
4. Look for the field you're interested in (in this case, Manufacturer and Manufacturer Model), and you should see the name of the graph extension that contains that field listed next to it.

Once you know the name of the graph extension, you can use that to get the extension instance for the current record, like this:

```
InventoryItem row = Base.ItemSettings.Current;
InventoryItemExt rowExt = row.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();
```

Replace "`InventoryItemExt`" with the name of the actual graph extension that contains the fields you're interested in.

Then you can access the Manufacturer and Manufacturer Model fields like this:

```
string manufacturer = rowExt.UsrManufacturer;
string model = rowExt.UsrManufacturerModel;
```

Replace "`UsrManufacturer`" and "`UsrManufacturerModel`" with the names of the actual fields in the graph extension that you're working with.

Comment: I'm familiar with that. The problem is that these fields are part of the field service DLL and as such aren't in a customization package I have access to. The core of the problem is that in the DAC Schema Browser they just say "Created in FSxEquipmentModel (PX.Objects.FS.dll)"